# What is the correct syntax for parenthesizing "products", "result", "pagenavigationbar" and "between"

Tags: punctuation, run-on-sentences, parenthesis

I don't know much about the syntax and semantic of the parenthetical phrases. I have made the following sentence:

> Suppose that we have created a context named “Products” using two anchors, “Results” as the beginning and “PageNavigationBar” as the ending anchors and "Between" as its scope.

*named “Products”*, *“Results” as the beginning and “PageNavigationBar” as the ending anchors and "Between" as its scope* are the parenthetical phrases.

I would like to get sure I used it in natural and correct way.

It's not for proofreading, its just an example of how parenthetical phrases are created. If there are other patterns, I would like to know them.

Comment: What exactly is the parethetical phrase in the sentence?

Comment: @pazzo I specified them in the sentence.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/8-types-of-parenthetical-phrases/. A quick fix for your sentence: *Suppose that we have created a context named “Products” using two anchors (“Results” as the beginning and “PageNavigationBar” as the ending anchors) and "Between" as its scope.* Using two commas in the place of the parentheses is okay too. However, I'd recommend using *and its scope named "Between"* instead of *and "Between" as its scope* for the parallelism (*a context name "Products"*, and *its scope named "Between"*).

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose that we have created a context named “Products” using two
>   anchors, “Results” as the beginning and “PageNavigationBar” as the
>   ending anchors and "Between" as its scope.

The sentence would benefit from simplification.

**Suppose that we have created a context using a starting anchor, "Results", and an ending anchor, "PageNavigationBar". Let's call the context "Products" and its scope "Between".**